# [{"non_field_errors": ["Expected a list of items."]}] when saving data in Django Rest with MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django. I am trying to save the json data using Django. I am using MongoDB as backend and one to many relationship approach to store data -  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Here is my model:

```
class OtherInfo(models.Model):
      info_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      info_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      info_3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return u'%s %s %s' % (self.info_1, self.info_2, self.info_3)


    class ModelInfo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     other_info = ListField(EmbeddedModelField(OtherInfo))

     def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.name, self.email)
```

Issue is -

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'])
def save(request, format=None):
    serializer = mySerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializer -

```
class other_info_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OtherInfo
        fields = ('info_1', 'info_2', 'info_3')


    class mySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      other_info=other_info_serializer(many=True)
      class Meta:
            model = ModelInfo
            fields = ('name', 'email','other_info')
```

I want this above information to be saved as below in DB

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   email: "email@example.com",
   other_info: [
                {
                  info_1 : "123 Fake Street",
                  info_2: "Faketon",
                },
                {
                  info_1: "1 Some Other Street",
                  info_2: "Boston",
                 }
              ]
 }
```

Now when I send post data in URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/save/

Parameter 1 : "name":"sample name" 
Parameter 2 : "email":"sample@email.com"
Parameter 3 : [{'info_1':'Google','info_2':'Save'},{'info_1':'Hackhathon','info_2':'Present'}]
```

On execution of the above request I get -

```
{"other_info": [{"non_field_errors": ["Expected a list of items."]}]}
```

Any suggestions on whats happening wrong ?

**Edit**

Tried passing name value pair as well. But still same issue.

```
Parameter 3 : "other_info" : [{'info_1':'Google','info_2':'Save'},{'info_1':'Hackhathon','info_2':'Present'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by `RelationsList` - it does not have own `save` function but parent serializer called it.

There is an exact same issue on [github issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1650).
And they says handling nested objects is still under heavy development phase. ([Link](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1457))

But I made [a patch for this](https://github.com/lqez/django-rest-framework/commit/dab34aa68815aaa10592459435b296c728c89988)(like below) and you can test it via [sample project](https://github.com/lqez/django-non-rel-test).

```
class RelationsList(list):
    _deleted = []

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        [obj.save(**kwargs) for obj in self]
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB always expects a name-value pair and you don't supply one at the third parameter:

```
 Parameter 3 : [{'info_1':'Google','info_2':'Save'},{'info_1':'Hackhathon','info_2':'Present'}]
```

Here you pass just an array of objects.
Your request must look like this:

```
 Parameter 3 : "other_info" : [{'info_1':'Google','info_2':'Save'},{'info_1':'Hackhathon','info_2':'Present'}]
```

Comment: Tried. Getting the same issue.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion ?